# How does MintAccont and Metadata Account linked to each other?

Tags: spl-token, token

Looking at this picture [image: Text] (From https://lorisleiva.com/owning-digital-assets-in-solana/how-nfts-are-represented-in-solana)

I have some questions:

1）what is the Mint Account data struct defined? Can some one share the source code link or doc?

2）Does token-program support using Metadata Account? or need to use token-program-2022 to use Metadata?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After do some research, I got the conclusion that, MintAccount DO NOT maintain have pointer/address to MetaDataAccount.

But they are logic linked. Provided a ATA account, retrieve MintAccount info, then by using {'metadata', MintAccount.key, token-metadata-program.ID} as seed, we can get the meta data (Though I haven't try it).

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's correct! At least, for Metaplex's metadata model